# Queuing Theory: Maths, CS, or Statistics?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted a question on queuing theory here, but as it hasn't raised much interest, or reflection, I'm tempted to ask whether it might be better transferred to another SE site.

Applied queuing theory seems to me more of an engineering discipline than a mathematical discipline, and as such may not be best served here; but if not, then where?

Any ideas?

Comment: As they say, *Now don't be hasty Master Meriadoc...* :-) I went as far as posting a comment to your question.

Comment: I like [your question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292768/distribution-of-server-utilisations-in-an-m-m-c-queuing-model-with-an-unusual-di) and suspect that Math.SE is the best fit for an analytic solution.  CrossValidated does seem to be pretty broaded in their coverage of topics, not just bread-and-butter statistics, so I would search there for queuing theory posts.

Comment: It depends what the question is. At [cs.se], we tend to prefer questions with some kind of computational aspect to them. It's not an absolute requirement, since many areas of pure mathematics are very relevant to computer science and computer scientists; but it's a decent rule of thumb.